# Getting Typescript error when assigning a string to React component's state using TS type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have created a React component's state for a type `Color`.

```
\\ state

const [messageSeverity, setMessageSeverity] = useState<Color>('success');

\\ TS type

export type Color = 'success' | 'info' | 'warning' | 'error';
```

However, I'm getting a TS error message `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Color>'` when trying to set a different value to the state by:

```
 setMessageSeverity('success');
```

How could I solve it? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the `Color` in question is your `Color`?  Navigate to the type to be sure (Ctrl-click on `Color` in your code in VSCode if that's your editor).  Chances are you're using some other `Color`, not yours.

Comment: If that's not the issue, you'll have to post more complete code because it looks perfectly fine otherwise.  In fact, I copied your code into a React component and it compiles fine.

Answer (score 1):

In a simple example running your snippets in Stackblitz I could not identify the problem when you execute a `setState` with a literal string like this:

```
setMessageSeverity('success');
```

You can see the code running [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-nxbvrs?file=App.tsx).

But sometimes, the TS compiler can't infer the type itself and define some variable with `string` instead of your specific type. In these cases you need to add hints:

```
// Code with TS error because infoText is inferred as string
const arr = ['success', 'info'];
const infoText = arr.find((x) => x === 'info');

// Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Color>'
const setToInfo2 = () => setMessageSeverity(infoText);
```

To fix it, just look at the types before the item:

```
// With array type now the compiler knows infoText as a Color item
const arr: Color[] = ['success', 'info'];
const infoText = arr.find((x) => x === 'info');

// No errors
const setToInfo2 = () => setMessageSeverity(infoText);
```

If something was not clear enough you can provide more info about your code, like a reproducible online example that we can analyze.